# Can't show/hide content in Blackberry OS 5 browser

Tags: html, blackberry

I'm having a problem with showing/hiding divs in a mobile app.

I have it working fine on Android and on Blackberry OS 6, but on Blackberry OS 5 it's just not working.

Apparently changing the display attribute doesn't work in OS 5.  Someone suggested trying the following:

> we toggled a class name. Every device except OS5 would have the class name toggle the display property, OS5, however, would toggle the height from auto to 0px

... but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

My app has multiple pages, each contained in its own div within a single HTML file. I can show the divs by setting their class to visiblePage, but I can't hide them (i.e. they remain visible after I set the class to hiddenPage). The result is that any page I've ever shown remains visible from that point onward.

Here's my CSS:

```
.hiddenPage {  /* used only on Blackberry OS 5 */
    height: 0px;
}

.visiblePage {  /* used only on Blackberry OS 5 */
    height: auto;
}
```

And here's my code:

```
x$("#" + currentPage)[0].setAttribute("class", "hiddenPage");
x$("#" + newpage)[0].setAttribute("class", "visiblePage");
```

(The x$ is just because I'm using XUI. I've verified that the x$(...) returns the correct nodes).

I'm currently testing in Ripple using OS 6, but the goal is to run under OS 5 (Ripple doesn't support OS 5).

If anyone can offer any suggestions, I'd really appreciate it.